# Remove all words from string that match a pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a string like

```
/usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub
```

Here, I want to remove all words that containing `/usr/bin/`. By word I mean space delimited.

So, `/usr/bin/gjs` and `/usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate` will be removed.

The resulting output will be `/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub`

What I tried so far is:

```
MY_COMMAND_PATH="/usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub"

WORD_TO_REMOVE="/usr/bin/gjs "

if [[ $MY_COMMAND_PATH == "/usr/bin/gjs "* ]]; then
    MY_COMMAND_PATH=${MY_COMMAND_PATH//$WORD_TO_REMOVE/}
fi

WORD_TO_REMOVE="/usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate "

if [[ $MY_COMMAND_PATH == "/usr/bin/gjs "* ]]; then
    MY_COMMAND_PATH=${MY_COMMAND_PATH//$WORD_TO_REMOVE/}
fi
```

But this is not scalable. Solutions like remove first two words will not work for me (this is a sample and there are edge cases) as well. The exact logic i need is "remove all the words is the sentence that contain `/usr/bin/`"

Comment: It is bad practice to use CAPS for shell variable names because global environment variables tend to be capitalized so if your variables are also using caps, that can lead to naming collisions. See, for example [here](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s7.1-function-names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple perl command:

```
$ string="/usr/bin/gjs /usr/bin/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate /media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub"
$ printf -- '%s\n' "$string" | perl -pe 's|\S*/usr/bin/\S*\s*||g'
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub
```

Or even with a sed that understands `\S` and `\s` (which mean "non-whitespace" and "whitespace" characters respectively):

```
$ printf -- '%s\n' "$string" | sed -E 's|\S*/usr/bin/\S*\s*||g'
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub
```

And even one that doesn't:

```
$ printf -- '%s\n' "$string" | /sed 's|[^[:blank:]]*/usr/bin/[^[:blank:]]*[[:blank:]]*||g'
/media/ismail/SSDWorking/book-collection/_Books/_misc/100 Things.epub
```